# Does RDF data instance have RDF Schema embedded in it?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

There exists a pre-defined norm for RDF Schema. I was wondering whether RDF data instance does have RDF Schema snippet embedded in it? Something like name of a class which also happens to be the name of a subject/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not necessary. You can have both separated the definition and the data. For instance if your create a FOAF document you won't be including the FOAF schema on it, but just using a reference to it like the followig (very simple snippet):

```
<foaf:Person rdf:about="#me" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <foaf:name>Dan Brickley</foaf:name>
  <foaf:mbox_sha1sum>241021fb0e6289f92815fc210f9e9137262c252e</foaf:mbox_sha1sum>
  <foaf:homepage rdf:resource="http://danbri.org/" />
  <foaf:img rdf:resource="/images/me.jpg" />
</foaf:Person>
```

Comment: The namespace URL (http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ in this example) is often considered a location for putting human readable documentation. Some consider it a place for putting machine readable documentation. There isn't yet a W3C recommendation on it, but my preference was always humans first!

Comment: However I agree (and upvoted on the basis that) using the namespace only is the convention. There is rdfs:isDefinedBy but its not seen very often. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-rdf-schema-20000327/#s2.3.5

Comment: Is true what you said Simon, there is no convention. However using Content Negotiation is it possible to have both human and machine readable version in the same URL. In fact the FOAF spec does that.

Comment: @simon-gibbs: Actually there is a recommendation or better a best practice document on how to publish RDF vocabularies: http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/